# Query for find the Primary and foreign Key Column and surrogate keys oracle sql

Tags: oracle, oracle-sql-data-modeler

I have two questions

1. I need to find out all the surrogate keys across the whole database schemas oracle sql ?
2. I need to find out all the Primary keys and Foreign keys across the whole database schemas oracle sql  ?

some fields for just an example

```
COLUMNNAME              DATATYPE          NULLABLE COLUMN_ID COMMENTS
CCC_CUSTCAT_SID         NUMBER(38,0)        No      1        Unique SURROGATE Key
CCC_NUM_SUBCATEGORY_UID NUMBER(22,0)        No      2        NATURAL key column 1, subcategory number
CCC_CATEGORY_SID        NUMBER(38,0)        No      3        FK: Unique SURROGATE Key of Category
CCC_MOD_CATEGORY_UID    VARCHAR2(300 BYTE)  No      4        NATURAL key column 2, Category UID
KCD_SUBSCR_TYPE_SID     NUMBER(38,0)        No      5        FK: Unique SURROGATE Key of SUBSCR type
KCD_MOD_SUBSCR_TYPE_UID VARCHAR2(300 BYTE)  No      6        NATURAL KEY column 3, SUBSCR type UID
```

so i have some confusion what is the real difference between surrogate keys vs Natural Key vs Primary keys vs Foreign Key ? when trying to understand searching through various post it's bit confusing ?

Basic understanding

PK - is not null field uniquely identified
FK - used for referencing

Natural Key - ?
Surrogate Key - ?
UID - ?
SID - ?

I have found some information

can some one explain and provide queries question - 1 and Question - 2

I have tries something , but getting error

```
SELECT ac.table_name,
         column_name,
         position,
         ac.constraint_name,
         DECODE (constraint_type, 'P', 'Primary Key', 'Foreign Key') key_type,
         (SELECT ac2.table_name
            FROM all_constraints ac2
           WHERE AC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = AC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            fK_to_table
    FROM all_cons_columns acc, all_constraints ac
   WHERE     acc.constraint_name = ac.constraint_name
         AND acc.table_name = ac.table_name
         AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P', 'R')
         --AND ac.table_name = 'ACCOUNT' (your table here)
ORDER BY table_name, constraint_type, position;

ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: Oracle has many views of metadata on tables (data dictionary).  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/tables014.htm#ADMIN01508

Answer (score 0):

Your scalar query

```
(SELECT ac2.table_name
            FROM all_constraints ac2
           WHERE AC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = AC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME)
```

can return more than one row, because more than 1 table could refer back to the same primary key constraint on a parent table.

A quick workaround is to collect them all, ie

```
SELECT ac.table_name,
         column_name,
         position,
         ac.constraint_name,
         DECODE (constraint_type, 'P', 'Primary Key', 'Foreign Key') key_type,
         (SELECT listagg(ac2.table_name) 
            FROM all_constraints ac2
           WHERE AC2.CONSTRAINT_NAME = AC.R_CONSTRAINT_NAME)
            fK_to_table
    FROM all_cons_columns acc, all_constraints ac
   WHERE     acc.constraint_name = ac.constraint_name
         AND acc.table_name = ac.table_name
         AND CONSTRAINT_TYPE IN ('P', 'R')
         --AND ac.table_name = 'ACCOUNT' (your table here)
ORDER BY table_name, constraint_type, position;
```

Comment: Many thanks for tuning the query ,but i am getting the below error ORA-02000: missing WITHIN keyword
02000. 00000 -  "missing %s keyword"
Error at Line: 7 Column: 13

Comment: Is that your entire query, or do you have a group by in there somewhere?  Also, what version of the database are you on

Comment: Hi @Connor McDonald i am getting the same error i have also tried using group by , i am using oracle 11.2.0.4